# Why am I getting HTTP ERROR 500 using PHPMailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm building a website and since the regular PHP mail() is pretty bad and slow I've decided to use PHPMailer. I've installed it using composer, but I'm stumbling upon an error. My browser (Google Chrome) gives the error:

'The page is not working, HTTP Error 500'

From the console log:

POST https://qliqdronten.nl/test/aanmelding.php 500 ()

The headers:
Request URL: https://qliqdronten.nl/test/aanmelding.php
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 
Remote Address: 84.244.181.151:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
[image]

I've also tried the recommending settings from the hosting provider and from hotmail but those don't seem to be the problem, as the problem occurs with every host.

If anyone has an idea, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Sander

EDIT: when I don't use composer but just use the files it won't work either.

```
 use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
        use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

        //Now include the following following files based 
        //on the correct file path. Third file is required only if you want to enable SMTP.

        require 'PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php';
        require 'PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php';
        require 'PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';

        $mail = new PHPMailer();
```

Comment: Check you have your error logging enabled and set appropriately, then tell us what the error message is.

Comment: Look at the error log. it should tell you whats wrong.

Comment: @JonStirling I have ini_set("display_errors","On"); in my code but that doesn't help. Really the only thing in the browser: https://puu.sh/BnutZ/b0050de183.png.

Comment: Right, but don't look in the browser, look in the error log.

Comment: 500 errors are on the server, not the client. Check your server's logs.

Comment: you need to enable display error to on in your php.ini file then restart your webserver, you need to see the actual php error

Comment: The error log seems to be completely empty... https://puu.sh/BnuUy/456bf09006.png

Comment: Do you have your display_error to on in your php.ini file?

Comment: The php.ini file is supposed to be in /usr/local/php56/lib/php.ini but I can't find this folder in my server files...

Comment: https://puu.sh/Bnvs8/cec5603a02.png